# MathJax not working when used between opening and closing HTML tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown, mathjax

Why does MathJax fails to work when used between opening and closing HTML tags.

Illustration:

When the markdown is `<p>The complexity is $O(n)$</p>`, the math is not rendered properly.

However, when the markdown is

```
<p>

The complexity is $O(n)$.</p>
```

the math is rendered properly.

Can someone please explain this behaviour ?

Also, what should one do when importing posts that contains such occurrences? Should I search for HTML tags and add a 'newline' after each of them ?

Thanks!

Edit: The tag 'ruby-on-rails' has been used because this is the case of Discourse (built on ruby-on-rails).

Comment: Post a live sample please.

Comment: You can try that in any Discourse powered site that has MathJax enabled, like https://forum.image.sc/

Comment: A link to an example that fails helps as well. Very likely it is a markdown processing issue.

Comment: Why are you using `<p>` tags in Markdown in the first place? You can create paragraphs by simply leaving blank lines...

Comment: It is not clear to me how this is failing from your question. Is this a failure of the Markdown parser or is this a failure of the MathJax library in the browser? Have you checked your browser's dev tools for error messages? If so, what are they?

Comment: Yes, I checked the console. No errors. 
I am not using <p> tags in Markdown. Users have used, and this worked in OSQA but is not working in Discourse. Hence, the question.